# Trouble in playing video from URL in iPhone using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios4, streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play a video through a link in my app. The code goes here

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:viewURL];

NSLog(@"Filepath is: %@", viewURL);

MPMoviePlayerController *movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playbackFinishedCallback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:movie];

movie.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 50.0f, 320.0f, 320.0f);
movie.fullscreen = YES;
[self.view addSubview:movie.view];

[movie play];
```

This was written in a method that is called on a button press. This code once worked but now there is no response from the code. Nothing happens when I click on the button even when I connected everything properly in my xib file.

Comment: You are saying that nothing happens - does that also imply that the NSLog is not executed?

Comment: NSLog does print the url but the media player dows not launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Remove

`[movie play];`

and add

```
movie.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[movie prepareToPlay];
```

instead.

Streaming movies (m3u8), from my experience, are a bit quirky when it comes to starting the playback. In certain situations, your original version won't work properly but my replacement always works.

EDIT:
You may also want to check your encodings and delivery using Apples Mediastream Validator as described by this [Best Practice Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html) and this [TechNote](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices).

Comment: Thanks for the response ..... but hard luck at my end ........ it did not work .... the oberver throws a notification that the server is not configured properly................ I am not able to understand that as well....

Comment: See my latest edit for checking your server side. And one note, sentence delimiters do not come in flocks ;).